# Select a single row of matrix as a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

This has been bugging me forever.  Consider the following:

```
# Part A #
# Make a silly simple matrix with column names
x = matrix(1:4, ncol = 2)
colnames(x) = c("a","b")

# Part B #
# Pick out the first row of the matrix.  This is not a matrix, 
#   and the column names are no longer accessible by colnames()
y = x[1,]
y
is.matrix(y)
colnames(y)

# Part C #
# But here is what I want:
y = matrix(x[1,], nrow = 1, dimnames = list(c(), colnames(x)))
```

Is there any way to achieve Part C with fewer processing steps, or less code?  It seems like there should be a command nearly as short as `x[1,]` that does the same thing.

Comment: You're not the only one bugged. A gem from Software for Data Analysis: "The default is, and always has been, drop=TRUE; probably an unwise decision on our part long ago, but now one of those backward-compatibility burdens that are unlikely to be changed."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set `drop=FALSE` as in:

```
> y = x[1,, drop=FALSE]
> y
     a b
[1,] 1 3
```

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
x[1,,drop=FALSE]
     a b
[1,] 1 3
```